# Very simple attempt of using DrawLine failing

Tags: c#, graphics

I know this is trivial, but I don't understand why nothing is drawn on the Form1 after I click the button:

```
namespace GeometryTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
            gr.Clear(Color.White);
            Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red,3);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, 20, 20, 200, 250);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try on `paint` event? try `base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics g;

            g = e.Graphics;` Or try [Drawing with Graphics in WinForms using C#](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/winforms-drawing-cs/)

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics(), it almost never does what you hope it does.  You'll splatter some pixels on the screen but they've got the survival skills of a mayfly.  Override OnPaint() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** you are using `PaintEventArgs` as parameter in `Button Click` event.
i even doubt that this will compile if you subscribe the `button1_Click` Event Handler to `Click` event of the `Button`.

**Solution 1:**
You need to `Subscribe/Register` to Button `Click` event as below:

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

and EventHandler should be as below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              //event handling code here
            }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
namespace GeometryTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }


       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
            gr.Clear(Color.White);
            Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red,3);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, 20, 20, 200, 250);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**  if you want to draw the line on Form_Paint event you can do subscribe to `Form_Paint` Event as below:

You need to `Subscribe/Register` to Form Paint event as below:

```
  this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
```

and EventHandler should be as below:

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
                {
                  //event handling code here
                }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
namespace GeometryTest
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
            }


           private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

           } 

            private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
           {

            System.Drawing.Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
            gr.Clear(Color.White);
            Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, 20, 20, 200, 250);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A silly beginner mistake was the problem: I made the button, and then typed "private void button1_Click..." (didn't double-click the button), and thought that would be enough to "associate" the event with the button. :)
But you are right, when I fixed that, it didn't compile because of what you said. Thank you!

Comment: @Eutherpy: You are welcome :) , you can see my edited answer with `solution 2` if you want to draw the line on Form Paint , have a nice day...

Comment: `System.Drawing.Graphics` should be wrapped in a `using` block as it is an `IDisposable` resource.